# Java equivalent of Go libtrust public key KeyId()

Tags: java, docker, hash

I am trying to write the Go code from the following tutorial in Java

https://medium.com/@adigunhammedolalekan/creating-docker-registry-token-authentication-server-with-go-1ce3aa030c17

I am stuck on the following

```
header := token.Header{
    Type:       "JWT",
    SigningAlg: algo,
    KeyID:      srv.pubKey.KeyID(),
}
```

This seems to be something specific to this library and reused in the docker registry service to verify the key used to sign is correct.

On GithUb there is some explanation within the code, ie

```
// KeyID returns a distinct identifier which is unique to this Public Key.
// The format generated by this library is a base32 encoding of a 240 bit
// hash of the public key data divided into 12 groups like so:
//    ABCD:EFGH:IJKL:MNOP:QRST:UVWX:YZ23:4567:ABCD:EFGH:IJKL:MNOP
KeyID() string
```

But, I have no precise idea of how to perform the above, for instance it talks about a hash but what kind of hash? Is there some off the shelf library for that somewhere?

Comment: The JWT `"kid"` header claim uniquely identifies the key used to sign the token; you can look it up in the response from a JWKS endpoint to verify it.  Beyond the same key ID being in both places, it can be any string.  Are you trying to implement your own JWT-producing service, or do something else?

Comment: Thanks. I'm using JJWT to implement the token auth server for the docker registry service. The specs are here https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/1b9ab303a477ded9bdd3fc97e9119fa8f9e58fca/docs/spec/auth/jwt.md

Comment: It seems like that link spells out the required form of `"kid"` pretty well ("a libtrust fingerprint compatible format", the first 240 bits of the SHA-256 hash of the public key with specific formatting).  It looks like [libtrust](https://github.com/docker/libtrust) is a (dead) Docker-authored open-source Go library and its GitHub repository might be a good starting point.

Comment: Ha! I can't believe I overlooked that bit, I've been focusing too much on the code. Thanks!